# Dafny simple assertion does not hold

Tags: dafny

In `exercise_1a` what could be done to make the assertion `cnt > 0` valid?

```
method exercise_1a(n: int)
    requires n > 0
{
    var idx := 0;
    var cnt := 0;

    while idx < n
        decreases n - idx
    {
        idx := idx + 1; 
        cnt := cnt + 1;
    }

    assert idx > 0; // valid
    assert cnt > 0; // *** invalid ***
}
```

Surprisingly, this version invalidates the assertion `idx > 0`, as well:

```
method exercise_1b(n: int)
    requires n > 0
{
    var idx := 0;
    var cnt := 0;

    while idx < n && cnt < n
        decreases n - idx
        decreases n - cnt
    {
        idx := idx + 1; 
        cnt := cnt + 1;
    }

    assert idx > 0; // *** invalid ***
    assert cnt > 0; // *** invalid ***
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your first snippet of code, when the `while` loop exits, all Dafny knows is that `!(idx < n)`. Therefore, it can infer that `idx > 0`. However, Dafny doesn't know anything about the `cnt` variable at this point, so your second assertion fails.

In the second snippet of code, when the `while` loop exits, all Dafny is knows is that `!(idx < n && cnt < n)` (again, the negation of the condition on the `while` loop). This is equivalent to `idx > n || cnt > n`. From there, Dafny could infer `idx > 0 || cnt > 0`, but it wouldn't be able to prove either `idx > 0` or `cnt > 0` on its own.

To fix this, you need to add some relation between the variables `cnt` and `idx` that Dafny could check and then use.

```
    while idx < n && cnt < n 
        decreases n - idx 
        decreases n - cnt 
        invariant idx == cnt 
    {   
        idx := idx + 1;  
        cnt := cnt + 1;
    }
```

The extra `invariant` line tells Dafny check that `idx == cnt` will hold across every iteration of the loop, and then it can use that fact at the end. However, Dafny would not know to bring the fact `idx == cnt` under consideration unless you tell it to do so.

(As a side note, you'll see that Dafny *is* able to determine, on its own, that `n > 0` holds at the end of the `while` loop, even while you don't specify it explicitly as in `invariant`. This is because `n` is not modified in the body of the while loop, so Dafny will automatically carry across the fact that `n > 0` from the beginning.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, tjhance. It seems I have a mistaken concept about the code analysis capability of Dafny.

Comment: I still don't understand why Dafny can't prove idx >= n in the second snippet (and it'd make the disjunction with cnt >= n true, independently from cnt) when it can in the first one. Regarding the additional invariant, what can be done if there's no direct relation between idx and cnt; for instance, idx indexes an array and cnt counts the occurrences of certain values in the array?

Comment: In the second snippet, it's possible (as far as Dafny knows) that the loop exits with `idx=0` and `cnt=n`. Remember that in trying to prove the last assertion, Dafny *doesn't consider the inside of the while loop at all*. The only information it can use is (i) the fact that that the while-loop condition is false and (ii) any invariants on the while loop.

Comment: "what can be done if there's no direct relation between idx and cnt; for instance, idx indexes an array and cnt counts the occurrences of certain values in the array?"
Honestly, it really depends on the specifics. You're trying to show `cnt > 0`; so you have to ask yourself why *you* believe that must be the case. For example, if `cnt` is counting occurrences of a certain value, then you'll need to know that said value appears at least once in order to prove `cnt > 0` at the end of the loop.